# How to change my default project in Firebase because of it I am unable to deploy my project

Tags: firebase

Every time I try to deploy my index.html. I get an error in this way and I literally have no idea how to handle this and how to change my Default Project.

[and my cmd #error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIpoI.png)

Tq if answered

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).